# ROS buildfarm CI fails with "UNSTABLE" status?

Tags: ros, buildfarm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

E.g. in [this PR](https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_camera/pull/56) ROS buildfarm CI failed but I cannot find anything actually failed in its CI [output](http://build.ros.org/job/Lpr__openni_camera__ubuntu_xenial_amd64/2/consoleFull), where the build result is `unstable`. While I understand that unstable is not ideal at all, I'm confused if it's still in releaseable condition or not. Particularly in the case of the same PR, ROS pre-release test passed ([its result on Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/ros-drivers/openni_camera/jobs/293900404)).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274482/ros-buildfarm-ci-fails-with-%22unstable%22-status?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2017-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you go to the page of the unstable build (http://build.ros.org/job/Lpr__openni_camera__ubuntu_xenial_amd64/2/) you will find that it has compiler warnings. That make the job unstable which on <s>Travis</s> GitHub is interpreted as a failure. Since that didn't prevent to build the Debian packages the release builds still pass.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-10-29**:
Thanks (I guess you meant the CI on ROS buildfarm, not Travis, since what failed is on buildfarm). A dumb question: should the CI fail for compiler warning like the case above?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2017-10-29**:
No, warnings as well as falling tests only make the Jenkins jobs unstable.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-10-30**:
Let me rephrase since I might have not been clear; Do you have any idea why GitHub shows red cross while Jenkins finished with unstable for the cited PR? Is that how the Jenkins' result supposed to be handled? This may be pure Jenkins-GitHub question but I'd appreciate if you could share insights.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2017-10-30**:
I updated my answer. Yes, GitHub interprets an unstable Jenkins job as a failure.